# How do I use pseudo selectors with material ui's styled api?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Referring to [this api](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api), I have my component like this so far:

```js
const ActionButton = styled(Button)({
    margin: '0 16px',
});
```

But now I want to use the `first-child` and `last-child` pseudo selectors but I'm not entirely sure how to achieve that with this particular API.

I've tried something like this:

```js
const ActionButton = styled(Button)({
    margin: '0 16px',
    ':first-child': {
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
    ':last-child': {
        marginRight: 0,
    },
});
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the most important part: the `&`.

```js
const ActionButton = styled(Button)({
    margin: '0 16px',
    '&:first-child': {
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
    '&:last-child': {
        marginRight: 0,
    },
});
```